# What is the correct format for replying to salam?

Tags: sunnah, arabic, greetings

While saying salam to others, nobody will say Wassalamu alaikum or Assalamu Walaikum. But, while replying I can hear different format like

> - Wa alaikum Wassalam
> - Wa alaikum Assalam
> - Alaikum Wassalam
> - Alaikum Assalam

Which one is correct?

Comment: Wa Alaikum Assalam Wa Rahmat-ul-Allah Wa Barakatuhu

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is:

> Wa Alaikum Assalam

Wikipedia has some good explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assalamu_alaikum#Correct_classical_response) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wa_alaykumu_s-salam).

Please note that there is a Hadith that requires you to return Salam same or better. That means if someone said:

```
Assalam-o-Alaikum Wa Rahmat-ul-Allah
```

You should say one of these:

```
- Wa Alaikum Assalam Wa Rahmat-ul-Allah 
- Wa Alaikum Assalam Wa Rahmat-ul-Allah Wa Barakatuhu
```

But just saying *Wa Alaikum Assalam* is not recommended.

Comment: As quoted in the new answer it is based on the Quran not a hadith that we are asked to answer or return with a better salam.

Answer (score 2):

Allah said,
وَإِذَا حُيِّيتُم بِتَحِيَّةٍ فَحَيُّواْ بِأَحْسَنَ مِنْهَآ أَوْ رُدُّوهَآ

(When you are greeted with a greeting, greet in return with what is better than it, or (at least) return it equally.) meaning, if the Muslim greets you with the Salam, then return the greeting with a better Salam, or at least equal to the Salam that was given. Therefore, the better Salam is recommended, while returning it equally is an obligation

If one says assalamualekum 
Then reply walekum assalam or walekum assalam vo rahmatullah
If one says assalamualekum vo rahmatullah
Then say walekum assalam vo rahmatullah or walekum assalam vo rahmatullahi vo barkatahu
If one says assalamualekum vo rahmatullahi vo barkatahu.
If one says saamualekum or other words simillar to salam then reply him with WA-ALYEKUM