# How should I reply to "Assalamu Alaikum"?

Tags: practical-islam, adab, greetings

What is the difference between responding with "*Alaikum Salaam/علیکم السلام*" and responding with "*Walaikum Salaam/وعلیکم السلام*"? Is it wrong to say "*Alaikum Salaam*" in reply to "*Assalamu Alaikum*"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct format for replying to salam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12366/what-is-the-correct-format-for-replying-to-salam)

Comment: @Farhan why close this if the answers here are much better elaborated?

Answer (score 7):

Well you can answer:

Alaikum as-salam عليكم السلام
or
wa alaikum as-salam  وعليكم السلام

Both are perfectly fine and good answers!

Also available are the singular forms:

- 'alaika as-salam عليك السلام
  and
- wa 'alaika as-salam [وعليك السلام](http://sunnah.com/adab/42/71)

and also to repeat with the same word

- 'alaika as-salam السلام عليك ... etc. all this five expressions can be referenced from the sunna, even if i only referenced one!

But what you should never do is greet or begin greeting by saying 'alaika ('alaikum) as-salam see [here](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:856). Note that this has it's origin in Arabic costumes of the time as they used to greet or send a greeting to a dead person this way, as the poet said:

> عليك سلام الله قيس بن عاصم  *   ورحمته ما شاء أن يترحما
> فما كان قيس هلكه هلك واحد  *   ولكنه بنيان قوم تهدما

while the Prophet (Peace be upon him) in his sunna also used the wording with "as-Salaamu alaikum السلام عليكم أهل دار قوم مؤمنين" when visiting the gravyard. So according to a quote of al-Khattabi in [tuhfat al ahodi](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?idfrom=5225&idto=5230&bk_no=56&ID=1719) (a commentary on sunan at-Tirmidhi) on this hadith. Muslims don't make a difference between greeting dead and living people.

The only difference between the two possibilities you mentioned is the letter/character "Waw" or "wa", "و" this additional character gives a direct answer to the greeting, as when you say

- as-salamu 'alaikum = peace be upon you

you express a kind of wish, therefore saying

- *wa* 'alaikum as-salam = peace be upon you *too* or literally translated *and* peace be upon you
- ('alaikum as-salam = peace be upon you)

As an answer makes a small but meaningful difference! As you somehow "include" the greeting of the other person in your answer!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 3):

**In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful**

Briefly speaking, typically, the first person who intends to say hello (as a greeting), he or she says:

- Assalamu Alaikum/Alaik

But the second one who want to reply to his or her Salam, tells:

- Alaikum/Alaika Salam (which demonstrates being the second part who is
  saying back his/her hello

Otherwise seemingly you can use both of these two forms in replying, although "Alaikumo Salam looks to be more accurate/formal in compare with the other form (in reply).