# Answering "Assalamu Alaikum"

Tags: greetings

If some one says my brother is saying Assalamu Alaikum To you than what would be his answer : WAALAIKUM MUSSALAM OR ALAIKA WAALAIKUM MUSSALAM

I NEED AN AUTHANTIC HADITH

Comment: Why do you need a Hadith for a grammar question?

Comment: [How should I replay to assalamu alaikum](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/how-should-i-reply-to-assalamu-alaikum) answers the question and includes some references.