# Why don't we say "subhanahu wa ta'ala" after saying "assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah"?

Tags: arabic, greetings, phrase

After saying Allah, it seems we're encouraged to say "subhanahu wa ta'ala" (meaning "the most glorified, the most high").  However, there seems to be exceptions to this, e.g., when we say "assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah" (meaning "peace and mercy of Allah be upon you").  We say this e.g. at the end of salah prayer.

**Question**: Why don't we say "subhanahu wa ta'ala" after saying "assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah"?

Comment: The meaning you quoted sounds rather wrong. But the question is valid aa it seems we usually praise or show more respect to our Prophet than to our Creator.

Comment: This answer may be relevant: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37534/21320

Comment: I think this answer maybe relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/12367/13438

Comment: A short answer that would suffice for me and may be for some others is that - that is how the Prophet ﷺ taught us, so that is how we do it.

Comment: And IMHO, this comes under the category of knowledge that does not benefit. And the Prophet ﷺ used to seek refuge from such knowledge. Ref https://sunnah.com/muslim:2722

Unfortunately, a whole lot of questions in this website fall into this category.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing things.

- "Allah subhanahu wa ta'ala" (meaning "the most glorified, the most high")
- "assalamu alaikum wa rahmatullah" (meaning "peace and mercy of Allah be upon you")

The first one is meant to *praise* Allah, and in doing so we mean **he is exempt from evil doings**. Of the [dictionary meanings](http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-ar/%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%AD/) of *تسبیح/سبح/سبّح*  is: عَظَّمَهُ وَمَجَّدَهُ **وَنَزَّهَهُ** ( glorify, magnify and know him free of any wrong/evil/misconduct)

*Many* times in Quran you will see the phrase *سبحانه* or *سبحانک* as in you're exalted. Perhaps among the most heard verses is:

### *قَالُوا سُبْحَانَكَ*

*They said, "Exalted are You;*

### *لَا عِلْمَ لَنَا إِلَّا مَا عَلَّمْتَنَا ۖ إِنَّكَ أَنتَ الْعَلِيمُ الْحَكِيمُ*

*we have no knowledge except what You have taught us. Indeed, it is You who is the Knowing, the Wise."[Baqara 32](https://quran.com/2/32)*

It's like the angels saying, oh no no no no, sure sure sure we know you are free from any error/evil doings.

--

Has your life ever gone so south that made you say or hear " Oh God, when will my misery end? ", "God why did you do this to me?" "God you killed those innocent children!!!" , " God why can't I also be rich?", "Why did you send an earthquake and kill all those families?"

But Allah is *free* from ALL wrongdoings.

---

The second one is meant as a form of dua. May Allah bring his bless you with his bounty and mercy.

So in the first phrase the focus is on Allah.
In the second phrase the focus is on bringing (making dua) for the blessing and mercies of Allah onto that person.